# Using MSMQ when you already have SQL Server and BizTalk

Tags: sql-server, msmq, biztalk

Simple question: Is there any good reason to add MSMQ to an existing messaging framework which already has multiple BizTalk and SQL Server nodes?

Here's the background: We have a messaging framework to process bills, the load is rather low right now (at most 10,000 a day), but it's ramping up. We use BizTalk and SQL Server for all the processing, and we started noticing a few timeouts when inserting (synchronously) into one of the databases (NOT the BizTalk message box). One of our senior programmers suggested we use MSMQ to save (asynchronously) the data that causes the timeout and process it later; the solution he designed works and it's about to be deployed, but I'm still wondering if that was the right decision, considering that we could have used BizTalk itself or SQL Server Service Broker (SSSB). There's a lot of discussions about those three technologies, but they're usually about having to choose one of them over the others, I haven't seen any case of anyone who already had BizTalk and SSSB and decided to add MSMQ to the mix. In our case I think it's an unnecessary addition to our technology stack, but that may be my own bias (and ignorance too), since I know SSSB better and never did anything big with MSMQ. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should figure out why your inserts are taking so long, and fix that instead.  10,000 / day is *nothing* for a decent box running SQL Server.

EDIT:

Adding any sort of asynchronous processing is a form of kicking the can down the road.  Assume your inserts take one minute (I realize they probably don't, but for argument's sake).  If you make your inserts asynchronous, you can still only handle 1440 inserts per day until you start falling behind.  You are always going to need to speed up your inserts eventually.

Now with that said, I don't think that there is any compelling benefit in this case of using MSMQ over SSSB (or vice-versa).  It could be argued that with MSMQ you need to hand-code a listener daemon that does your inserts, whereas with SSSB you have that automatically within the database.  On the other hand, with MSMQ you are offloading the storage of the messages to another server, potentially offloading some of the immediate stress from your SQL Server.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, does it?

Comment: Your question, as near as I can tell is "What do you think?".  I took that to mean is [MSMQ] "an unnecessary addition to our technology stack".  The implication of my answer is "probably, yes", and the reasoning is that you shouldn't need so much time to do a simple insert.

Comment: Gotcha, but realize that the db is not dedicated to those inserts only, it's heavily used by other processes, and the bill messages that are inserted come with images. And no matter how much you tweak the db, when the load increases the problem may come back, so why not try to fix it right now? Asynchronous processing is the way to go, I'm just asking about choosing MSMQ over the other two solutions .

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that if you just wanted to take the database calls off-line then you could do that with BizTalk (for example, by creating an "offline" host - thereby creating a new host queue).

Where msmq really excels is on the inbound side of BizTalk. Systems can call to BizTalk not caring about the availability of BizTalk itself. The messages will just hang around until BizTalk is available again.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking for a good reason NOT to do that and use MSMQ instead.

Comment: So you can say that you can achieve the same result at lower cost with the existing tool set.

Comment: What I mean is much as I like MSMQ as a technology, I can't give you a good reason to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with Hugh - we've used MSMQ (and IBM MQ Series) successfully with BizTalk for asynchronous, transactional traffic (mostly financial transactions, where the need for traceable, reliable, ACID type message delivery outweighs any need for transaction latency).

We've found the benefits of MSMQ to be:

- Transactional delivery - messages can be pulled off by the destination system and inserted into SQL under a 2 phase UOW.
- Hugh's point about delivery decoupled from system availability (and you still have the Dead Letter Queue if the target system is down for an unreasonable period of time)
- Load balancing / throttling - a destination system can protect against overzealous message delivery by pulling messages off the queue at a more even pace.
- Auditing - using the journalling on MSMQ allows an additional layer of tracing.
- Also note that there is a WCF adapter for MSMQ - no requirement for custom listeners.

We generally stay away from calling SQL directly from BizTalk:

- For reading this equates to polling the database in the hope that there are messages ready to be sent (this can create issues relating to frequency of calling, i.e. redundancy, induced latency, and load on SQL, and contention - e.g. polling while data is being added by an app to the tables. We would rather have each app decide when to submit messages to BizTalk / ESB.
- for write operations, unless data is offloaded into a staging area for processing by destination apps, it can lead to much of the 'business' processing moving into BizTalk (i.e. validation, applying business rules etc) - IMHO this is too fine-grained for BizTalk. And as you've found, it can be hard to control the rate of message delivery into SQL (e.g. unless you start using Singleton Orhcestrations etc), which again causes locking / contention issues.